# MYSQL Alias select as string

Tags: mysql

I try to make 2 operations at the same time. I have a column named STORE_ID in MYTABLE and I want to select it as alias and convert it to string in the same time.

I tried this with no succes:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(STORE_ID as VARCHAR(50)) as STORE_ID_STRING
FROM MYTABLE
```

Need this to define a table in Mondrian 4 schema and I only can do this with one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to mysql documentation on [CAST() and CONVERT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast), varchar cannot be used as type, only char:

```
SELECT 
CAST(STORE_ID as CHAR(50)) as STORE_ID_STRING
FROM MYTABLE
```